Looking for a children's book series with three main characters and horses
I read this series around ten years ago, give or take a few years. There are three main characters, all girls. One of their names was either Lucy or Lulu, but started with an L. There are three horses. It's possible that all three of them with their horses were on the front cover. I think there was a brown horse (or something like brown), a white horse, and a pony. This is also a series with possibly over five books. Each book has its own unique plot.
Is there a book series that matches this description?

Could the girls have been named Suzy, Alexa, and Lucy?

@ClaraDíazSanchez I don't remember any of the names except that one definitely starts with an L.

Maybe the Pony Pals series by Jeanne Betancourt?

@Ayshe I think it is, but I'm not entirely sure. Their names sound very familiar though. And the horses match.
